# Ajax calls to encoded Internationalized domain names with jQuery 1.5 doesn't work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery-1.5, idn

Using jQuery 1.5 or 1.5.1, any ajax() calls to encoded [Internationalized domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (IDN) (like xn--bcher-kva.ch) seems to fail in Internet Explorer 8. It worked fine in jQuery 1.4.4 and also with 1.5+ in any other browser than IE. It also works when using the unencoded domain name.

Can anyone with deeper knowledge of jQuery and access to a IDN confirm or help with this? We only have access to one IDN, which belongs to a customer (which is why we unfortunately can't provide a proper test case). It would be great if someone else could confirm this before posting an official bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You sure it's not a cache problem?

try to add:

```
var timestamp = new Date();
```

And add this to the end of your argument list

```
"&timestamp=" + timestamp.getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tested adding your code to our test and got the same result as before in IE8 (the ajax error callback is triggered with the not so helpful "error" in the textstatus variable and jqXHR.responseText as "undefined").